# Putting together a shed on a slight slope

Tags: shed, asphalt, leveling

I'm hoping to put together a shed that's on a slight slope. It will sit on top of asphalt. What should I use to make sure the floor is level? Some 2x4's? Should I bolt the 2x4's to the asphalt before putting the shed on top? I am totally new at all things DIY. Thank you!

Comment: That depends largely on your shed design (mostly with respect to the floor and joist span). Please edit your post to add details.

Comment: Asphalt is soft.  If you put any kind of weight into the shed proper or its contents, it'll sink right in.  As a minimum you need to dig proper footings and mount the shed to a levelled frame.